# crystal report formatting

Tags: crystal-reports, width

I have field 'MRP' in crystal report. The maximum value for the field will be 999.99. How can i set the width of the filed to 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to resize the Field in the designer to your required width.  Crystal Reports doesn't resize the field based on the width of the content.